# What open source projects can be used for extracting relevant content from various webpages?

Tags: url, open-source

So for example the youtube video ID from a youtube page,  or a tweet ID from a twitter page, or a Facebook uid from a facebook profile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oembed protocol has a specification for accessing structured relevant data based on a URL. embed.ly is a company that procides an api based on that standard.

- http://www.oembed.com/
- http://embed.ly/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an open source project for that.  Lifting the ID from the page is usually a matter of parsing the URL that got you there.  In youtube's case, the "v" querystring parameter indicates the video ID.  The other examples have similar answers.

Comment: Scott, Youtube only is easy. What if I want to do that for 100 site types?

Comment: @David Haddad: Can you clarify your question then?  You want a generic way to extract what exactly from arbitrary web pages?  Just the identifying ID?  Semantic information?

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain. The main content of a page changes from one page type to the other. So let's say if you pass it the link to a tweet page, then the main output would be the tweet_id, twitterer, and the tweet text. It would vary from one site to the other. However if you do the same with a youtube video link, it would send you the youtube video ID/title/etc...

Comment: @David Haddad: I am pretty sure you're not going to find any project that is prewritten that just knows all the specific formats of every popular social networking/web 2.0 site and can parse it for you.